# Unrecognized option "knpu_guard" under "security.firewalls.main" (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, facebook-login, symfony-3.2, php-7.1

I would like to add facebook login option to my website. I try to follow [this tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/guard/social-login). But if I add the `knpu_guard` part under the main section, I get this error:

```
Unrecognized option "knpu_guard" under "security.firewalls.main"
```

My `firewalls` section in the `security.yml` looks like this:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        #pattern:    ^/
        provider: our_db_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        knpu_guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.form_login_authenticator
                - app.api_token_authenticator
                - app.facebook_authenticator
            # by default, use the start() function from FormLoginAuthenticator
            entry_point: app.form_login_authenticator
```

I just added the `knpu_guard` section, nothing else changed under the `firewalls` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the tutorial is a little bit obsolete because `knpu_guard` is no longer accepted.

You can use `guard` instead as a key in the `security.yml` file

[Discussion](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/knpuniversity/creating_a_login_form_part_1/)

Try to use this

```
form_login:
   login_path: login
   check_path: login
   provider: user_provider #where is this provider? It shouldn't be fos_userbundle for example?
anonymous: true
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "app.form_login_authenticator".`

Comment: I have update the answer but It's difficult to understand well the problem now

Comment: The users are stored in the db. My `User` class implements `UserInterface`. I do not use `fos_userbundle`